# Anchor unit tests wont work on localnet

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, local-cluster

Sorry for the noob question.

Im trying to test a program that I deployed locally, however when running `anchor run test`, I receive the following error.

```
Error: failed to get recent blockhash: FetchError: request to http://localhost:8899/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8899
```

Ive verified `solana-test-validator` is running, and I can airdrop lamports no problem. Additionally, I'll see the logs from bpf loader when deploying the program.

Anchor.toml checks out I believe. Pasted in the programid already. Same with declare_id! in lib.rs.

I honestly have no clue, any help would be soo appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using anchor with local validator and not it's own validator, you need to pass in the `--skip-local-validator` option like so:

```
anchor test --skip-local-validator
```